# What kinds of objects can Swing JTree nodes be?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I have been carefully following the [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) tutorial, which explains how one can use Swing's JTree setup to display trees.

In the examples however, I have noticed that the "tree objects" are just simple strings that are displayed. Example:

[image]

I tried seeing if I could set up a tree that would display a small textbox (ExpressionInputBox) someone set up using [RSyntaxTextArea] and [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), but I just end up getting the following happening: [image]

[Bigger link to picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9FiI.png)

What can I do to have the ExpressionInputBox show up as the nodes of the tree? Is there a limitation to what kind of objects JTree nodes can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, a JTree node can be objects ***any*** class as long as it implements the TreeNode or MutableTreeNode interface. That's it. You can even use classes that *don't* implement the interface as long as you provide a wrapper class that does.

Now you ask also:

> What can I do to have the ExpressionInputBox show up as the nodes of the tree? Is there a limitation to what kind of objects JTree nodes can be?

This is a two-parter, and in the wrong order.

- Again, for an object to be a viable node, its class must implement TreeNode.
- To display it *well* (and well is the key), you will likely want to create a TreeCellRenderer that works well with it.

Comment: So I just extend the ExpressionInputBox with TreeNode?

Comment: @twirlobite: we're talking *interface*, and so you **implement**, and myself, I'd implement MutableTreeNode or extend DefaultMutableTreeNode.